# Yahoo weather rss feed for Canada

Tags: rss, weather, yahoo-weather-api

My application uses yahoo's weather feed (XML) to display the weather forecast for the next 5 days. This works nice when the zip code is in the US. For example, the url below gets me the feed for Franklin, MI.

```
http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/48025_f.xml
```

I need a similar feed for Canada too, but cant seem to get it working. For example, the postal code of 'Scarborough' is M1M1M1. Tried with

```
http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/M1M1M1_f.xml
```

but that does not work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using reliably:

```
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=location
```

where `w = WOEID` and for `Scarborough, Canada` `w=4369` so:

```
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=4369
```

will return correctly the weather data. More information on the API [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/).

I'm also using this method for getting the `WOEID` for a given location name string:

```
// Create new XML doc
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
// Get XML doc
xmldoc.Load(string.Format("http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q({0})?appid={1}", place, ApplicationID));
string woeid = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("woeid")[0].InnerText;
return woeid;
```

But for this to work you will need to obtain an `ApplicationID` from `Yahoo` by registering your application.

Comment: Thanks for the response Florin.. A followup question to your answer. Is there a way to get the forecast for the next 3 days ? I see that the forecast is only for the next day when we use the above url. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Unfortunately no, this feed will only give you the forecast for next day.